# How to generate hyperlinks in table using go template

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to generate an html table which includes some hyperlink strings in one table cell.
e.g,

```
<a href="http://logd/logs/2800643/">2800643</a> 
<a href="http://logd/logs/2800795/">2800795</a> 
<a href="http://logd/logs/2801109/">2801109</a>
```

I've defined one template which can handle the table very well except this hyperlink thing.

```
{{ range . }}
<tr>
<td>{{ .Name }}</td>
<td>{{ .Logs }}</td>
</tr>
{{ end }}
```

Here I want to have Logs to be hyperlinked.
If I pass a formatted string into Logs here, `<` `>` will be parsed like below:

```
&lt;a href=&#34;http://logd/logs/2801103/&#34;&gt;2801103&lt;/a&gt
```

Based on the information I learned from go website, looks like I need to define another template embedded into this one.
Suppose it's to replace `{{ .Logs }}` here. Like:

```
{{ range . }}
<a href="http://logd/logs/{{.LogID}}/">{{.LogID}}</a>
{{ end }}
```

Wonder is there any example available ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist especially for html an [html-template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) which uses [type html](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML):

> HTML encapsulates a known safe HTML document fragment.

That means:

> Based on the information I learned from go website, looks like I need to define another template embedded into this one. Suppose it's to replace {{ .Logs }} here.

Instead of using string, use type html in your struct.